# Configure Login Audit - Skip one user-

Tags: sql-server

I have configured the login audit to save only the failed ones, but I need to omit a specific login in said audit, is it possible?

I am using sqlserver 2008-r2

Thanks.

Comment: Please add more details, how did you set it up? Where it is writing?

Comment: in server property --> security --> Failed logins only. write in error log

Comment: Upgrade to a more current version of SQL Server and you can filter logins. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it there.  But you can set up a server audit and exclude specific login.  I have not tested the code in 2008 R2.  Change you login value with `LoginName`. You can also use `server_principal_id` instead of `server_principal_name`.

```
USE [master]

GO

CREATE SERVER AUDIT [FailedLogin]
TO FILE 
(   FILEPATH = N'C:\'
    ,MAXSIZE = 64 MB
    ,MAX_FILES = 50
    ,RESERVE_DISK_SPACE = OFF
)
WITH
(   QUEUE_DELAY = 1000
    ,ON_FAILURE = CONTINUE
)
WHERE server_principal_name <> 'LoginName'

GO

USE [master]

GO

CREATE SERVER AUDIT SPECIFICATION [ServerAuditSpecificationFailedLogin]
FOR SERVER AUDIT [FailedLogin]
ADD (FAILED_LOGIN_GROUP)

GO
```